# How to make geoip_country_name_by_name() work?

Tags: php, geoip

I want to collect country name of an user who logined to my site. So i used

`geoip_country_name_by_name()` php function for this purpose.

But i got a fatal error as :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_country_name_by_name()
```

How can i avoid this error ?

Is there any other method to get country name using php?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure the GeoIP module is installed?

Comment: Do you have geoip installed? It's not a base library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need the PECL extension, have a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.installation.php

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the extension is not installed on your computer. Check out this link, it is a PECL extension.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php