# How to Get 2 Digit Country Code by Using php

Tags: php, xampp

Hello Friends I was Developing an website which i only want to be viewed by Indian (People of india) , and ***I Want to Get The Two Digit Country Code*** for that using php. I browsed to [http://php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) and tried using `geoip_country_code_by_name` , `geoip_country_code3_by_name` and `geoip_country_name_by_name` but None of Function worked , I have tried on my Existing XAMPP Installation and W3schools PHP runner but it says function not exists and i also have checked to PHP version. What Should i Do. I also Have tried methods form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842003/php-intl-country-code-2-chars-to-country-name) and after Google(ing) whole day i finally came to ask here .
***Feel Free to Suggest Edit or Close this Question***

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know the country of origin of the person who is viewing your website and block access to people from other countries - that's one. And number two is also identifying the indian country itself of the person.   If I am right what you need to do is not solvable by a function... origin of viewer is found via ip and dns... which you can get through php alone. but you also need a service to check the ip data through and receive from it the origin information (also your two digit codes). There are free services such as MaxMind I believe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821974/how-to-make-geoip-country-name-by-name-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some research, the best way seems to be by IP. This link will help you if you go this way.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13600004/13604954

But some VPN can easily change is on IP.
ref. https://nordvpn.com/blog/vpn-ip-location-changer/

So good luck!

The easiest way will be to asking the user is country and if not what you want, just show another page.

Comment: No problem,  its a pleasure. 